# Set a value in Model field based on another value from other model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models where one has a ForeignKey relationship with other entity. The thing is the date in `data_start` field from ModelB needs to be not equal and grater than the date in `date_end` from ModelA. How can I do this comparison(rule) inside the ModelB and save it?

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateTimeField('')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField('')

class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField('')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField('')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(ModelB,...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more correct to check this condition from `ModelA`, because in your structure there can be several `ModelA` instances for one `ModelB` instance, and it is not clear with which variant of `ModelA` compare date in this case.

So [override save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) of `ModelA` and check condition there

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField('')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField('')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(ModelB,...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date_end <= self.resource.date_start:
            raise Exception("resource.date_start can't be equal or grater then date_end")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Make sense doing this in modelA, because I was thinking in the following flow: A user create a instance of modelA through a form, so when then user choose the date from modelA it'll chosse a date from modelB, so when then gonna save the comparison will gonna happen